# ctypes.c_wchar_p("Some String") is only returning "S"

Tags: python, ctypes

I'm sending a string to a C function using ctypes. I believe I should be doing it this way:

```
    wchar = ctypes.c_wchar_p("tb.xrtl.d_bfm")
    print(wchar.value)
    c_lib.send_op(wchar, 5, 6, 4)
```

Which prints out

```
tb.xrtl.d_bfm
```

At the other end `send_op` looks like this:

```
void send_op(const char* path, unsigned char A, unsigned char B, unsigned char op){
    printf("****PATH IS  %s and is %d long", path, strlen(path));
}
```

It prints this:

```
****PATH IS  t and is 1 long
```

So I seem to be getting either a short string or one with a null in the second spot.

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

That API does not want `wchar_t`.  A `wchar` is a 16-bit Unicode value.  So, the buffer you send will be "'t' 0 'b' 0 '.' 0...", and C will see it as a one-character string.

Just use plain `c_char_p`.

Comment: I see. It works with c_char_p and b'tb.xrtl.d_bfm'

Must be specified as bytes.